# FindClusters behaves strangely when an argument for number of clusters is passed

Tags: cluster-analysis

I have a question about `FindClusters` function. It seems that it behaves rather strangely when I pass a specific dataset to it. I am trying to use it in a bigger set of code, but I will illustrate my issue with an example.

Suppose we have the following list:

```
{0.79828, 0.0066479, 0.588481, 0.61007, 0., 0.00166839, 0.00498368, 0.674149, 0.662627, 0.0003537,
0.00822986, 0.00438603, 0.595791, 0.00667167, 0.297568, 0.000147291, 0.290336,
0.0128546, 0.793574, 0.00505361, 0.00254154, 0.00502201, 0.0170808, 0.018445, 0.0127057,
0.00720843, 0.00539111, 0.0201769, 0.0102616, 0.00579664, 0.00455612,0.00840309, 0.00307958,
0.0054002, 0.00730627, 0.000430262, 0.0211624}
```

When I use `FindClusters` by itself, i.e. without an argument for the number of clusters, the output is 2 clusters:

```
FindClusters[{0.79828, 0.0066479, 0.588481, 0.61007, 0., 
  0.00166839, 0.00498368, 0.674149, 0.662627, 0.0003537, 0.00822986, 
  0.00438603, 0.595791, 0.00667167, 0.297568, 0.000147291, 0.290336, 
  0.0128546, 0.793574, 0.00505361, 0.00254154, 0.00502201, 0.0170808, 
  0.018445, 0.0127057, 0.00720843, 0.00539111, 0.0201769, 0.0102616, 
  0.00579664, 0.00455612, 0.00840309, 0.00307958, 0.0054002, 
  0.00730627, 0.000430262, 0.0211624}]

{{0.79828, 0.588481, 0.61007, 0.674149, 0.662627, 0.595791, 
  0.297568, 0.290336, 0.793574}, {0.0066479, 0., 0.00166839, 
  0.00498368, 0.0003537, 0.00822986, 0.00438603, 0.00667167, 
  0.000147291, 0.0128546, 0.00505361, 0.00254154, 0.00502201, 
  0.0170808, 0.018445, 0.0127057, 0.00720843, 0.00539111, 0.0201769, 
  0.0102616, 0.00579664, 0.00455612, 0.00840309, 0.00307958, 
  0.0054002, 0.00730627, 0.000430262, 0.0211624}}
```

This is the result I expect since the values I would like to separate are the ones close to 0. We can see that the values close to 0.8, 0.6, 0.7 and 0.3 are in the same cluster, while the values close to 0 are in a different one.

So far, I understand, however, when I force `FindClusters` to look specifically for 2 clusters I get the following:

```
FindClusters[{0.79828, 0.0066479, 0.588481, 0.61007, 0., 
  0.00166839, 0.00498368, 0.674149, 0.662627, 0.0003537, 0.00822986, 
  0.00438603, 0.595791, 0.00667167, 0.297568, 0.000147291, 0.290336, 
  0.0128546, 0.793574, 0.00505361, 0.00254154, 0.00502201, 0.0170808, 
  0.018445, 0.0127057, 0.00720843, 0.00539111, 0.0201769, 0.0102616, 
  0.00579664, 0.00455612, 0.00840309, 0.00307958, 0.0054002, 
  0.00730627, 0.000430262, 0.0211624}, 2]

{{0.79828, 0.588481, 0.61007, 0.674149, 0.662627, 0.595791, 
  0.793574}, {0.0066479, 0., 0.00166839, 0.00498368, 0.0003537, 
  0.00822986, 0.00438603, 0.00667167, 0.297568, 0.000147291, 0.290336,
   0.0128546, 0.00505361, 0.00254154, 0.00502201, 0.0170808, 0.018445,
   0.0127057, 0.00720843, 0.00539111, 0.0201769, 0.0102616, 
  0.00579664, 0.00455612, 0.00840309, 0.00307958, 0.0054002, 
  0.00730627, 0.000430262, 0.0211624}}
```

As you can see the values close to 0.8, 0.6, 0.7 are in the same cluster again, but this time, the values close to 0.3 are actually in the other cluster - with the values close to 0. Does anyone have any idea why that happens? I tried playing around with the `DistanceFunction` argument but that didn't really help.

I want to able to separate my data (this is just a sample and it is likely that real data will be with a lot more variance) in 2 clusters, where one cluster is the values close to 0 and the other is everything else. I would prefer not using a threshold and have a more data driven approach. My main concern here is that `FindClusters` appears to be less reproducible than I hoped. Perhaps I don't understand how the function actually works.

Thank you for any comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is likely because the clustering method selected by `FindClusters` changes between the two calls.

In fact, of the methods available to `FindClusters`:

- some can *only* be used *with* a pre-specified number of clusters (`"KMeans"`, `"KMedoids"`);
- others only work when the number of clusters is *not* specified (`"DBSCAN"`, `"NeighborhoodContraction"`", `"JarvisPatrick"`, `"GaussianMixture"`);
- only `"Agglomerate"`, `"SpanningTree"`, and `"Spectral"` work *both with and without* a specified number of clusters (but **they may return different results in either case**).

I suspect that, in your case, **the automatically selected methods are different between the two calls**.

For reproducibility (and for publication and dissemination), it is often a good idea to explicitly specify a method using the `Method ->`  option: that will go a long way towards making the answers you get more reproducible.

See also [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/249871/27951) to indirectly figure out which methods `FindClusters` is likely selecting in either case. The method proposed originally in the accepted answer to that question unfortunately no longer works, but `ClusterClassify` exhibits similar behavior, switching between DBSCAN and "Agglomerate" depending on whether the number of clusters is or is not specified:

```
ClusterClassify[data]
ClusterClassify[data, 2]
```

[image: classifier functions returned by clusterclassify show different methods]

---

For instance, let's compare the results of different methods on your data when the number of clusters is or is not specified (In the code, `data` is your list of values):

```
{#, Length@ FindClusters[data, Method -> #]}& /@ 
     {"Agglomerate", "DBSCAN", "NeighborhoodContraction", 
      "JarvisPatrick", "MeanShift", "SpanningTree", 
      "Spectral", "GaussianMixture"}

(*Out:
{{Agglomerate, 5},
 {DBSCAN, 2},
 {NeighborhoodContraction, 5},
 {JarvisPatrick, 37},
 {MeanShift, 5},
 {SpanningTree, 4},
 {Spectral, 10},
 {GaussianMixture, 1}} *)
```

... and specifically requesting 2 clusters:

```
{#, Length@ FindClusters[data, 2, Method -> #]}& /@     
     {"Agglomerate", "KMeans", "KMedoids",
      "SpanningTree", "Spectral"}

(* Out:
{{Agglomerate, 2},
 {KMeans, 2},
 {KMedoids, 2},
 {SpanningTree, 2},
 {Spectral, 2}} *)
```

Comment: Hi Marco, thank you for the explanation - it is much clearer now. I think I will follow your advice and specify the method I want to use. Thanks again!